# Как правильно создать массив String из файла .csv WPF

Tags: c#, массивы, wpf, строки, split

Моя программа должна загружать данные из файла .csv в таблицу datatable.
Для этой цели, я решил использовать разбивку строк из файла на массив из отдельных элементов с последующим их присвоением datatable. Но массив не работает, т.к. в нем нет необходимого количества элементов. Как правильно осуществить задуманное? (Сразу уточню, пишется таблица без проблем, все колонки и строки сохраняются).

Файл csv выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Personal_Budget_Assistant__Main_
{
    class BudgetItem //класс для хранения данных
    {
        private DateTime _Date { get; set; }
        public string Date => _Date.ToShortDateString();
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Expense { get; set; }
        public decimal Income { get; set; }

        public decimal Savings { get; set; }

        public BudgetItem(DateTime date, string name, decimal expense, decimal income, decimal savings)
        {
            _Date = date;
            Name = name;
            Expense = expense;
            Income = income;
            Savings = savings;
        }


    }
}
```

А это уже в MainWindow:

```
private void fillingDataGridView() //сама таблица
    {
        DataColumn date = new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        DataColumn name = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(String));
        DataColumn expenses = new DataColumn("Expenses", typeof(decimal));
        DataColumn income = new DataColumn("Income", typeof(decimal));
        DataColumn savings = new DataColumn("Savings", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add(date);
        dt.Columns.Add(name);
        dt.Columns.Add(expenses);
        dt.Columns.Add(income);
        dt.Columns.Add(savings);
    }


 private void FillDataTableFromCSV() //основной метод заполнения таблицы
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            new BindingList<BudgetItem>();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName);
                string curLine = sr.ReadLine(); // <- ignore header row
                if (curLine != null)
                {
                BudgetItem BI;
                BI = GetBudgetItemFromString(curLine);
                    while ((curLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (BI!= null)
                        {
                        dt.Rows.Add(BI);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error invalid Budget Item: " + curLine);
                        break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
        }


private BudgetItem GetBudgetItemFromString(string data) //вспомогательный метод, преобразующий строки в искомые данные для таблицы
{
  string[] arr = data.Split('\t'); /* не создается массив (от 0 до 4)
  ошибка типа: "за пределами массива"*/
    if (arr.Length >= 5)
    {
    DateTime.TryParse(arr[0], out DateTime date); /*здесь я преобразую
    значения из файла в тип, понимаемый таблицей*/
        Convert.ToString(arr[1]);
        decimal.TryParse(arr[2], out decimal exp);
        decimal.TryParse(arr[3], out decimal inc);
        decimal.TryParse(arr[4], out decimal sav);
        return new BudgetItem(date, arr[1], exp, inc, sav);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Array is wrong!");
   return null;
}
```

И, на всякий случай, метод сохранения (работает без проблем):

```
private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    var lines = new List<string>();

    string[] columnNames = dt.Columns
        .Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Select(column => column.ColumnName)
        .ToArray();

    var header = string.Join(",", columnNames.Select(name => $"\"{name}\""));
    lines.Add(header);

    var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Select(val => $"\"{val}\"")));

    lines.AddRange(valueLines);
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == true)
        File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog1.SafeFileName, lines);
}
```

Comment: BudgetItem используй как DTO, где каждый объект содержит одну строку. OvservableCollection<BudgetItem> как DataGrid.ItemSource.
Так же лучше использовать MVVM паттерн и привязки, а не Code Behinde...

Comment: Вы бы хоть для примера дали пару строчек своего csv, у вас же проблема здесь `string[] arr = data.Split('\t');`? Или где?

Comment: Да, проблема здесь. Exception выпадает вот тут   Convert.ToString(arr[1]); System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
Строчки в csv сейчас приложу скриншотом.

Comment: Если, кстати, вывести длину массива arr в MessageBox, то выдает значение "1". Подозреваю, что проблема кроется в ('\t') у Split, что приводит к созданию только 1 элемента массива

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку исправил:

```
string[] arr = data.Split(',');
```

Добавил у `Split` не `('\t')`, а `(',')`.